# Find correlations between variables selected from shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to find the correlations based on the `shiny` widgets' variables selection  but I cant make it work properly as I get `undefined columns selected`.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

var1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var2 <- c(2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5)

# Create categorical variables
var3 <- c("red", "green", "blue", "red", "green")
var4 <- c("small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium")
var5 <- c("red1", "green1", "blue1", "red1", "green1")
var6 <- c("small1", "medium2", "large2", "small2", "medium2")
# Combine variables into a dataframe
mmtcars <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4,var5,var6)

# app page
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      "vars", 
      "Select variables", 
      choices = colnames(mmtcars), 
      selected = colnames(mmtcars)[1:2], 
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    plotOutput("mlr_output")
  )
)

# server side actions
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Convert categorical variable to a factor
  mmtcars$var3 <- factor(mmtcars$var3)
  mmtcars$var4 <- factor(mmtcars$var4)
  mmtcars$var5 <- factor(mmtcars$var5)
  mmtcars$var6 <- factor(mmtcars$var6)
  
  # Subset the data into numeric and categorical variables
  numeric_vars <- mmtcars[, sapply(mmtcars, is.numeric)]
  categorical_vars <- mmtcars[, sapply(mmtcars, is.factor)]
  
  mm <- reactive({
    # Compute the correlation matrix between selected numeric and categorical variables
    selected_numeric_vars <- numeric_vars[,  names(numeric_vars) %in% input$vars]
    selected_categorical_vars <- categorical_vars[, names(categorical_vars) %in% input$vars]
    
    if (length(selected_categorical_vars)>0) {
      var_c <- as.numeric(selected_categorical_vars)-1
      df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars, varc  = var_c)
      names(df)[length(names(df))] <- names(categorical_vars)[names(categorical_vars) %in% input$vars]
    }else df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars)
    
    #correlations <- cor(selected_numeric_vars, as.numeric(selected_categorical_vars) - 1, method = "pearson")
    correlations <- cor(df)
    correlations
  })
  
  
  # print summary of correlation matrix for selected variables
  output$mlr_output <- renderPrint({mm()})
  
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The error occurs when you select a factor variable (in your case, `am`).  There would be no `am` in `numeric_vars` because only numeric variables are included in `numeric_vars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

mmtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(row_name = rownames(mtcars))

# app page
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      "vars", 
      "Select variables", 
      choices = colnames(mmtcars), 
      selected = colnames(mmtcars)[1:2], 
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    verbatimTextOutput("mlr_output")
  )
)

# server side actions
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Convert categorical variable to a factor
  mmtcars$am <- factor(mmtcars$am)
  mmtcars$row_name <- factor(mmtcars$row_name)
  # Subset the data into numeric and categorical variables
  numeric_vars <- mmtcars[, sapply(mmtcars, is.numeric)]
  categorical_vars <- mmtcars[, sapply(mmtcars, is.factor)]
  
  mm <- reactive({
    # Compute the correlation matrix between selected numeric and categorical variables
    selected_numeric_vars <- numeric_vars[,  names(numeric_vars) %in% input$vars]
    selected_categorical_vars <- categorical_vars[, names(categorical_vars) %in% input$vars]
    
    if (length(selected_categorical_vars)>0) {
      var_c <- as.numeric(selected_categorical_vars)-1
      df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars, varc  = var_c)
      names(df)[length(names(df))] <- names(categorical_vars)[names(categorical_vars) %in% input$vars]
    }else df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars)
    
    #correlations <- cor(selected_numeric_vars, as.numeric(selected_categorical_vars) - 1, method = "pearson")
    correlations <- cor(df)
    correlations
  })
  
  
  # print summary of correlation matrix for selected variables
  output$mlr_output <- renderPrint({mm()})
  
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks it works but only if I select only one factor variable.

Comment: You need to replace `varc = var_c` with a dataframe - depending on your use case.

Comment: I dont understand for example mmtcars instead of varc=var_c?

Comment: Modify `mm` reactive object to your needs.  Use a different dataset with multiple factor variables as your sample.

Comment: ok I have edited with data with multiple factor vars

Comment: Please check how `cor()` works.  You need numeric variables.

Comment: I dont understand why this works with only one categorical which is turned to factor then but I created a new question